# i3-wm not resizing screen resolution on login

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, multi-monitor, i3, parallels

I'm using Parallels for the Mac, but this may be relevant to other VMs too.

Using Ubuntu 14.04, when I login using Unity it resizes the screen and uses all available screens (2 in my case), perfect. However, I'd rather use i3wm, but when I login, it doesn't resize the screen (it's stuck on 1024x768), and doesn't use my extra monitor.

Not sure if this is a i3 thing or a Parallels/VM thing, or both.

Comment: Did you read the instructions on [Multiple monitors](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#multi_monitor) in the i3 documentation? If this doesn't help, it might still be a good idea to add the output of `xrandr` (when using i3wm and maybe when using Unity) to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your xrandr you could use this api to use multiple monitors, as damien said you the better way to solve this situation is using :

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1
```

asuming that your first screen is **LVDS1** and you want to use your **VGA1** port.

> --auto

is for autodetection of recommended resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed from [this wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328235244/http://www.digriz.org.uk/debian/parallels-macbookpro) worked for me:

```
xrandr &> /dev/null
prlcc &
```

Comment: Link of the wiki was dead. Found more info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/parallels